# How can I determine IE version now that I updated to jQuery 1.9?

Tags: jquery, version, browser-detection

Most of the work done for my app supports the oldest IE8, so how can I detect that user has IE8 or higher?

Comment: [Use conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx), like you should have been doing all along.

Comment: @Ankit browser.version is deprecated in 1.9?!

Comment: What do you want to do if the user isn't using IE8+?

Comment: @KevinB just a warning message saying unsupported version i guess, cause the css in ie7 is crap... and some functionality.

Comment: If the only issue is CSS, i'd just let it look like crap, as long as it is still functional. Chances are if they're using IE7 they're used to things looking like crap.

Comment: @KevinB when i say crap, it's more like stuff is all over the place i guess. im currently trying out jquery migrate and using $.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 7, havent done a full test yet but it seems to be working.. i was hoping for an easier method without bringing in migrate..

Comment: well, what are you doing for IE7 exactly? if you're just hiding content and showing a message, that can be done with conditional comments alone.

Comment: @KevinB do you mean what blazemonger suggested?

Comment: @yaojiang yes, exactly.